# Exclude Current Week till Wednesday SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

```
If     DATENAME('weekday', TODAY()) = 'Sunday'
     then [Date] <= TODAY()-1
  elseif DATENAME('weekday', TODAY()) = 'Monday'
     then [Date] <= TODAY()-2
  elseif DATENAME('weekday', TODAY()) = 'Tuesday'
     then [Date] <= TODAY()-3

else [Date] = [Date]
end
```

I am using this calculation in Tableau. I need to use similar logic in SQL query which has weekly aggregated data for weeks. So how to **exclude current week until Wednesday** (while showing all previous weeks data).

| Date_week | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 | 30 |
| 021-10-31 | 40 |
| 2021-11-07 | 90 |
| 2021-11-14 | 130 |
| 2021-11-21 | 200 |

**I need to not show CURRENT week 2021-11-21 until it is Wednesday i.e. 2021-11-24**
.
same for the current weeks in the future!

Comment: can you please add the data sample?

Answer (score 0):

use `case statements`:

```
select * 
from table 
where [Date] <= case DATENAME('weekday', TODAY()) 
       when 'Sunday'  then TODAY()-1
       when 'Monday'  then TODAY()-2
       when 'Tuesday' then TODAY()-3
       else TODAY()
```